# How to send code to interactive R console in VS Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up VS Code for use with R following the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r). I have installed the R extension in VS Code as well as the languageserver package and started an interactive R session in the terminal built in to VS Code.

When I type code directly into the console (say `1+1`), the result is displayed. However, when I execute the same line of code from an R script, it is not sent to the console in the right way:

[image]

How could I fix this?

**Solution:**

Turns out a recent MacOS update requires `r.bracketedPaste` to be set to `false`. See https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/1246

Comment: How did you execute the line of code from the R script?

Comment: With Cmd + Enter while the cursor was positioned within the line. When I click on the "Run Source" button instead, I get the following error: `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "00~source("/Users/.../test.R", encoding = "UTF-8")01"` ..as if some text was added to the actual code. Could this be an encoding issue? UTF-8 sounds fine to me though

Comment: This is strange because your way is the standard way (equivalent to ctrl+enter in Windows, I believe) and should work if you didn't make any customization. Did the answer by @rioV8 work? You can also try sending something but to another type of terminal, to see if this problem also occurred for other languages and terminals.

Comment: which command is bound to `Cmd + Enter`, use key GUI

Comment: `Run Source` will not work because you have a R REPL running, use a regular terminal with command prompt for this

Comment: Thank you all, I finally found the solution here: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/1246 (added to the original post).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#interminal)

Select the text you want to send to the terminal and press the given key binding:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i f5",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
    "args": {
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": { "text": "${selectedText}" },
      "addCR": true
    }
  }
```